Conjugate function in Wolfram Mathematica does not work for long sums
I need to conjugate some sum of terms. Wolfram Mathematica does this for short sums, but not for long ones.
Click here to see a screenshot of Wolfram Mathematica with formatted code.
Raw code:
Ass = Assumptions -> {Element[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g}, Reals]}
A := (-I)*c*(1 - d)*e*E^(I*(a + b)) + (1 - d)*f*(-E^(I*(a + b))) + E^(I*a)*g
FullSimplify[Conjugate[A], Ass]

How to get WM to conjugate expression completely?

Ass=Assumptions->{Element[{a,b,c,d,e,f,g},Reals]};
A:=(-I)*c*(1-d)*e*E^(I*(a+b));
B:=(1-d)*f*(-E^(I*(a+b)))+E^(I*a)*g;
FullSimplify[Conjugate[A]+Conjugate[B],Ass]

returns
E^(-I(a+b))((-1+d)(-I c e+f)+E^(I b)g)

Please check that carefully before you trust it.
I would be cautious and think carefully about when Conjugate[A]+Conjugate[B]==Conjugate[A+B]
ProofWiki seems to agree with this, but I would still be cautious with products and complex exponentials involved

Thank you for your replay. Of course I can calculate the conjugation myself, but I figured WM should do the job itself. I don't see the point in WM calculating short expressions and being lazy on longer ones. The given expression is an intermediate result of a computation that could be much longer. And breaking them manually into short fragments seems ridiculous. Especially if you don't know what length is required.

@Alex2414 I realize that many people believe Mathematica should do exactly what they want and give the correct answer and give the result in exactly the form that they want and even format it in exactly they style they expect. Why it didn't give the result you wanted with the input you gave... we will likely never know. You are obviously free to think this is ridiculous. I try to find ways to coax Mathematica into providing an answer and try to convince myself that is correct then caution everyone to try to make as certain as we can possibly be that what I did gave a correct answer. Up to you.
